# Can't send mail via Pony and Ruby Sinatra, getting "End of File" error

Tags: ruby, email, sinatra, eof, pony

I am trying to send mail through Pony and for some reason this "End of File" error shows up.........

```
EOFError at /contact-us
end of file reached
file: buffering.rb location: sysread_nonblock line: 182
```

Here's the setup:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

set :views, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/views'
set :public_folder, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/public'


get '/' do 
    erb :index
end

get '/overview' do
    erb :overview
end

get '/our-mission' do
    erb :mission
end

get '/customers' do
    erb :customers
end

get '/retail-support' do
    erb :retail
end

get '/contact-us' do
    erb :contact
end

post '/contact-us' do
    require 'pony'
    first_name  = params[:first_name]
    last_name = params[:last_name]
    mail = params[:mail]
    subject = params[:subject]
    body  = params[:body]

Pony.mail({
    :to => 'merchandising@nlm-marketing.com',
    :from => first_name + '<' + mail + '>',
    :reply_to => mail,
    :subject => subject,
    :body => body, 
    :via => :smtp,
    :via_options => {
        :address => 'smtp.zoho.com',
        :port => 465,
        :user_name => 'username',
        :password => 'password',
        :authentication => :login,
        :ssl => true,
        :tls => true,
        :enable_starttls_auto => true

    }
    })



    redirect '/success'
end

get '/success' do 
    erb :success
end
```

And here's the backtrace:

```
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb in sysread_nonblock
      return sysread_nonblock(maxlen, buf, exception: exception)
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb in read_nonblock
      return sysread_nonblock(maxlen, buf, exception: exception)
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb in rbuf_fill
        @rbuf << @io.read_nonblock(BUFSIZE)
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb in readuntil
          rbuf_fill
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb in readline
      readuntil("\n").chop
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb in recv_response
        line = @socket.readline
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb in block in getok
        recv_response()
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb in critical
        return yield()
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb in getok
      res = critical {
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb in quit
      getok('QUIT')
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb in do_finish
      quit if @socket and not @socket.closed? and not @error_occurred
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb in ensure in start
          do_finish
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb in start
          do_finish
main.rb in block in <main>
Pony.mail({
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb in service
      si.service(req, res)
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb in run
          server.service(req, res)
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb in block in start_thread
          block ? block.call(sock) : run(sock)
```

I have no idea why I'm receiving the error. What is going on and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Is that the whole file? It looks like you're missing an `end`.

Comment: No that is not the whole file and it does have an end